# Cygwin Split Terminal Vertically

Tags: cygwin

I've read online to split the window to do Ctrl+a | or Ctrl+a Shift+S but its not working for me. I am hoping I'm just missing a setting somewhere in cygwin or maybe need to upgrade something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see that option for Cygwin itself, but those commands match up to options in GNU Screen: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

Comment: Ok thanks, for some reason I thought I had done this before but maybe I was just splitting a vim window. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install Tmux ?

IN the latest Cygwin version it's included in it's package. For more info refer to: 
https://gist.github.com/zlalanne/8188248